# What the Process to transfer the staging table data to Fact tables in Snowflake by Custom Validations

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

good Day.
I need help. I want to ***transfer the data in Snowflake from Staging tables to Fact tables*** automatically, when data is available in Stage table. While moving data from Staging table to Fact tables, I have couple of Custom validations on each column and row.
Any idea how to do this in Snowflake.
If any one knows could you please suggest me...!
Thanks in Advance...!

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this and how you go about it depends on what tools you have available. The simplest way to do this without using tools outside of the Snowflake ecosystem would be:

1. On each of the staging tables you have, set up a stream on these tables ([here is the Snowflake documentation on streams](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/streams.html))
2. Create a task that runs on a schedule ([here is the Snowflake doc on tasks](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/tasks-intro.html)) to pull from the streams and write into the fact table.

This is really a general data warehousing question rather than a Snowflake one. [Here is some more documentation](https://www.snowflake.com/blog/building-a-type-2-slowly-changing-dimension-in-snowflake-using-streams-and-tasks-part-1/) on building SCD type 2 dimensions also written by someone at Snowflake

Comment: Thank you sooooooooo much dude Simon. I will do some work around and let you know. Thanks a lot for quick turn out...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "staging tables" refers to a Snowflake table and not a file in a Snowflake stage, I would recommend using a Stream and Task for this.  A stream will identify the delta of data that needs to be loaded, and a Task can execute on a schedule and will only actually run something if there is data in the stream.  Create a stored procedure that is executed in the Task to run your validations and Merge the outcome of those into your Fact.

Comment: Thank you so much dude Mike.